# Trouble positioning custom navigationItem titleView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a custom view (`titleView`) that I've created for a webView on my iOS app. The `titleView` has two labels, a `titleLabel` and a `subTitleLabel`. If the `titleLabel` is too wide for the `titleView`, I truncate the text and have it fill the whole frame. But the problem happens whenever the `titleLabel` is smaller that the `titleView`. I get inconsistent results when I try to calculate the position of the `titleLabel`'s frame. I just assumed I would take the difference between the width of the `titelView.frame.size.width` and the `titleLabel.frame.size.width`and divide that by 2, but it doesn't work. I'm probably missing something stupid, but I just can't see it. One thing to note is that the `subTitleLabel`'s seem to be positioned fairly well, and though it's not perfect, it's better than the `titleLabel`'s.

Here are some images (I added borders to the `titleView` and it's subViews to help show positioning) that show positioning with various length title strings:

[image: offset to the left]
[image: slightly offset to the right]

Code:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 88, 34)];
titleView.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16 weight:UIFontWeightThin];
UIFont *speakerFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10 weight:UIFontWeightLight];

CGSize speakerSize = [[self.speech speakerFullNameAndDate] sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : speakerFont }];
CGSize titleSize = [self.speech.title sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : titleFont }];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

[titleView addSubview: titleLabel];
[titleView addSubview:subTitleLabel];

CGFloat titleDifference = (titleView.frame.size.width - titleLabel.frame.size.width) / 2;

titleLabel.text = self.speech.title;
titleLabel.font = titleFont;
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

// titleLabel is bigger than the titleView's frame
if (titleSize.width > titleView.frame.size.width) {
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, titleView.frame.size.width - 20, 18);
} else {
    // titleDifference / 3 seems to be the best number for the frame's x coordinate
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(titleDifference / 3, 0, titleSize.width, 18);
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
}

subTitleLabel.text = [self.speech speakerFullNameAndDate];
subTitleLabel.font = speakerFont;
subTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
subTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
// Again, ((titleView.frame.size.width - speakerSize.width) / 3) seems to work best, though it's far from perfect
subTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(((titleView.frame.size.width - speakerSize.width) / 3), 20, speakerSize.width, 12);
[subTitleLabel sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269968/4475605

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating your title label origin wrong remember that any view origin is the top left corner, so your title label origin should be something like

```
CGFloat originX = titelView.frame.size.width/2 - titleLabel.frame.size.width/2
```

what you are doing is assuming a view origin is in the center of the view