# How to set navigationItem.titleView image horizontal center?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar, swift3

I have simple project inside im using `UINavigationBar` inside `UIImageView` logo but some views my logo looking `30-40px` right side or some views looking `50-60px` left side.

How to set navigationItem.titleView image horizontal center?

My code is below:

```
        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 164, height: 38))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Output picture:

[image]

Also when I change `x:50` to `x:80` or `x:0` etc., nothing happened!

Comment: can yiu some output what type do u need

Comment: try to set  x origin 0

Comment: @kirtimali i try to set 0 but another views looking bad

Comment: [This relative question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258879/uinavigationitem-centering-the-title) might be helpful.

Comment: How does it look if you set frame origin is 0? like that it will be in center

Comment: @Tj3n same logo goes left side a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set x origin 0 like

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 164, height: 38))
```

Comment: i try to set 0 but another views looking bad

Comment: also if i wrote there 50 or 60 in iphone 5 looking too bad.

Comment: i added picture in my question same logo going 100 px more right side when comming navigation back left side icon